# Blob is being truncated when saving to Oracle table

Tags: java, jdbc

When saving an image to an Oracle table as a blob, the blob is sometimes being truncated.

If an image gets truncated, it is always truncated in the same place.

Also, it's not a size issue, which is the first obvious answer.  One image that truncates is 126Kb, and one that is fine is 3Mb

The blob column doesn't have a size specified, so according to Oracle it defaults to 2Gb.

The java code is:

```
OutputStream os = null;
try {
    os = image.getImage().getBinaryOutputStream();
    os.write(uploadFile.getFileData());

} catch (Exception e) {
    af = mapping.findForward("imageProblem");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This was caused because I'd forgotten to close the OutputStream.  It was being garbage collected (I assume), in a surprisingly deterministic fashion before it had finished writing the blob to the table.  Closing the stream fixed the issue:

```
OutputStream os = null;
try {
    os = image.getImage().getBinaryOutputStream();
    os.write(uploadFile.getFileData());

} catch (Exception e) {
    af = mapping.findForward("imageProblem");
} finally {
    if (os != null) {
      os.close();
    }
}
```